# Problem understanding definition of ordering on stationary sets

Tags: set-theory

In the book "Set Theory" of Thomas Jech, it is defined for any two stationary subsets $S,T$ of a regular uncountable cardinal $\kappa$, $S<T$ if and only if $S\cap\alpha$ is stationary in $\alpha$ for almost all $\alpha\in T$.

The author previously states:

"In the context of closed unbounded and stationary sets we use the phrase *for almost all* $\alpha\in S$ to mean that the set of all contrary $\alpha\in S$ is nonstationary".

I don't know what the author means by "contrary", thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is some statement about ordinals, the statement

> $P(\alpha)$ is true for almost all $\alpha\in S$

means that $\{\alpha\in S:P(\alpha)\text{ is false}\}$ is non-stationary. By *the set of all contrary* $\alpha$ he means simply $\{\alpha\in S:P(\alpha)\text{ is false}\}$.

Comment: @Camilo: You’re welcome.